# Compare in Sq Lite 3 Python

Tags: python, database, sqlite, compare, local

I have an Sq Lite 3 database which has the columns ID,name and time.
So I have the last row and placed in a var LAST_PERSON using python.

```
your_rank = "SELECT usr_name,time FROM rank WHERE ID = (SELECT MAX(ID)  FROM rank)"
```

I also have a var ROW which loops through each row sorted order by time.

```
sql = "SELECT usr_name,time FROM rank ORDER BY time "

for row in cur.execute(sql):
```

I want to compare:

> your_rank with the sorted by time row and get that last person's rank

I tried

```
        for row in cur.execute(sql):
        sql_list.append(row)
        if(row is your_rank):
            this_is_your_rank = rank_number
        rank_number += 1
```

But I cannot use the if statements for Sq Lite 3 and I have not being able to find any solution to compare these. Can you anyone give me a click?

If you cannot, thanks taking your time to reading.

Comment: Your python code is not properly indented and therefore invalid. You don't properly describe what you want to achieve. Most likely it can be done with a single SQL statement, but it's impossible to know which one, because you don't explain what you're trying to do.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You want to `select count(ID) from rank where time < your_time` or similar.

Looping over SQL results to find out what you want is clunky when you can just ask the database to give you the answer you want.

Edit:

Your first query, where you join the table to itself to get the user with the highest ID, can be:

```
SELECT MAX(ID),usr_name,time FROM rank
```

And you can combine them both together into "get the most recent user name, time, and their position" with:

```
SELECT 
    MAX(ID),usr_name,time, (SELECT COUNT(ID)+1 FROM rank WHERE time < r.time) [Pos]
FROM
    rank r
```

Edit again, oh ok ok. Instead of "can anyone give me a solution?", it's not clear what you mean by "I can't use the if statement", but here's some speculation:

If you actually typed in `row is your_rank`, assuming you actually executed the your_rank SQL query and saved the result over the top in the same variable name, then it fails because `is` is a Python keyword for testing whether two things *are the same thing* (that is, one thing with two names). It does not test whether two separate things *have the same value*. `==` is the equality test.

It also might fail because the result of a SQL query is effectively a *list of tuples*. Each `row` is *a tuple* and, depending on what you did to put the result in `your_rank`, they won't ever match when compared.

This might work, if you want to keep the same approach:

```
last_user = cursor.execute('select max(id),usr_name,time from rank').fetchone()

last_user_rank = 1
for row in cursor.execute('select id,usr_name,time from rank order by time asc'):
    if last_user[2] > row[2]:
        last_user_rank += 1
    else:
        break

print last_user, last_user_rank
```